# Why is Perl 6's right associativity not right?

Tags: raku, associativity

Clickbaity title but it's too meaty to pass up. I have this operator which I want to be right associative:

```
sub infix:<↑> ( Int:D \n, Int:D \m  --> Int:D )
    is assoc<right>
    is equiv(&infix:<**>)
    { n ** m }

put "2**2**2**2 = ",      2**2**2**2;
put "2↑2↑2↑2 = ",         2↑2↑2↑2;
put "2↑ (2↑ (2↑2) ) = ",  2↑ (2↑ (2↑2) );
```

It's not right associative:

```
2**2**2**2 = 65536
2↑2↑2↑2 = 256
2↑ (2↑ (2↑2) ) = 65536
```

What am I not doing right (*ahem*)?

Comment: If we swap lines 2 and 3, everything is OK. `2**2**2**2 = 65536
2↑2↑2↑2 = 65536
2↑ (2↑ (2↑2) ) = 65536`. Seems that precedence has higher precedence. :)

Comment: Make that an answer and I can accept that. I just figured that out too by selectively commenting out code.

Comment: https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132713

Comment: There's already Zoffix's answer, which thoroughly clarifies the matter. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like there's a can of bugs here...

First, `is assoc` in this particular case is not needed. As `is equiv` [copies all the options](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1730), not just precedence, and `&infix:<**>` is right-associative.

The reason it doesn't work is because [some guy broke it in Apr. 2017](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/f9f0883c6cef3695c5150d336f5e6552e1be4a4c), by having it delete `assoc` (essentially setting it to left-associate).

I've now reverted that commit, but [in a branch](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/6f5b27ce63) because the revert exercises [RT#132711](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132711#ticket-history), which is what original deletion of `assoc` tried to fix. <s>I'll give a go in fixing that bug this weekend and then will merge the fix for `is equiv`.</s> *UPDATE: It actually explodes in EXPR parser. My rakudo haxor level isn't high enough to work on that thing yet, so I'll leave it to someone smarter, for now.*

P.S.: you can save a few chars by writing infixes as `&[**]` instead of `&infix:<**>`